# Is it possible to mount these pieces of equipment vertically, together?

Tags: router, switch, mount, dell, rackmount

I have a Cisco 2811 and 2950 and a Dell PowerEdge R720 server.

I have the 2811 and the 2950 in a wall mount that holds the two pieces of equipment vertically (the jacks are facing upwards).

**I'm wondering if it is possible to mount all three of my pieces of equipment in a style similar to the one I have already. Where all of the devices front panels are facing up.**

Is there such a mounting solution and can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want the front panels facing up?

Comment: Well I suppose they don't need to be up. If the face panel of the server were up I'd be able to power the server up and insert cd/dvd media/keyboards/usb/and even drives with ease.

Comment: There are open-faced racks that wall mount and can accommodate full servers - We have a few at work that are on hinges and have a locking front as well, but those are optional features

Comment: See comment below, the rack I suggested wouldn't work. For a server you need a normal, horizontal rack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CHTIN9W) is a 6U wall mount rack that seems to have what you want.

I was able to find it by Google searching for `vertical wall mount equipment rack bracket 6u`. If I didn't specify the 6u on the end, it would just give me 1-6u options.

Comment: Nice! But this is why I come here to ask these questions. So the equipment that I want to mount to this device would just stack on top of each other? Or do I need to purchase one of these per each machine I have?

Comment: On most SE sites this type of question would be closed - this one still might because it's a product recommendation. By stacking, I am not sure what you mean - the purpose of this rack is to mount things vertically; your patch cables would be facing up, and the power cords would be near the ground. If you used a normal wall-mount rack the server would be like it's sitting on your desk, and you could still access the CD drive / router

Comment: I understand that. I was taking a risk when I first posted the question.
Perhaps I need to see the mounting solution in use to understand.

Comment: It's this concept, except it could hold more stuff: http://www.lowellmfg.com/userfiles/photos/18020823245446c74437215.jpg ... if you consider buying the one I posted, make sure your 3 pieces of equipment are 2U or less or they won't fit

Comment: Very clever. I see it now.

Comment: This rack is not appropriate for the equipment the OP is describing.

Comment: @ewwhite Why is that?

Comment: The proper rack would need to accommodate square holes and cage nuts and be rated to support the server's weight. An example of something that *would* work is: http://www.racksolutions.com/wall-racks.html - It is intended to be used with the server rail kit. The OP would need two units; one for the server and another for the networking equipment. Also see: http://serverfault.com/questions/281113/can-a-switch-be-wall-mounted-using-rack-mounts/281116#281116

Comment: @ewwhite The rack mentioned is 6U (there are 3 devices, 4u total), if you wanted to add some space. The one listed is rated at 200 pounds, and for servers, just not with rails - which is not needed for this type of enclosure, or necessary for a single server presumably for tinkering. Not trying to argue, I just don't believe a horizontal rack with rails is necessary, and I just stated what OP asked for

Comment: Actually, the rails *are* required. Dell and HP servers that use rails are not designed to be supported by their front bezel rack ears.

Comment: Ah you're right, I forgot about that. This rack would not be appropriate then for a server due to not being able to mount the backs of the rails.